# Launching Roo Shell adds all aspect files to change sets

Tags: ide, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, jazz

I am currently working on a Spring Roo application.  Our Roo version is 1.0.2, our source control system is Jazz Team Server 1.0.0.2 (iFix3), and IDE is a packaged version of Eclipse (SpringSource Tool Suite 2.3.2).

I generally fire up the Roo Shell for my project as soon as the IDE opens.  My problem is that this action always "dirties" all of my project's autogenerated aspect files and adds them to my pending changes list.  A comparison of the files shows what looks like the addition of whitespace to the end of each line.  I usually just undo these pending changes before I proceed with my work as I don't want change sets with hundreds of unchanged aspect files.

I have searched for an IDE setting to suppress these changes, but have not found anything that seems relevant.  Has anyone else had this happen and found a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in Spring Roo.  I'd suggest raising a jira for this here:

https://jira.springframework.org/browse/ROO